# Symfony Mapping Error: "The mappings are inconsistent with each other" & "The association refers to the inverse side field which does not exist"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I got two entities mapped as follows:

```php
class ScriptFeedback
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Script", inversedBy="feedback")
     */
    private $script;

    ...
}

class Script
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ScriptFeedback", mappedBy="script")
     */
    private $feebdack;

    ...
}
```

This works - I can generate migrations from this and the site works exactly how I want it to, correctly linking my scripts and their feedback in the DB.

However - when I run `doctrine:schema:validate` I get:

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\Script' mapping
>   is invalid:
>   * The mappings AppBundle\Entity\Script#feebdack and AppBundle\Entity\ScriptFeedback#script are inconsistent with each
>   other.
>
> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'AppBundle\Entity\ScriptFeedback'
>   mapping is invalid:
>   * The association AppBundle\Entity\ScriptFeedback#script refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\Script#feedback which does not
>   exist.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: You've got a typo at `feebdack`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of this annotation:

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Script", inversedBy="feedback")
```

You have a typo in your Script entity

```
private $feebdack;
```

should be

```
private $feedback;
```

Comment: Well I spent a lot longer trying to resolve this than I care to admit. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I've had this kind of error plenty of times while creating doctrine relations. It is often just a small typo problem or forgeting to declare inverse side property.